# String index out of range despite iterating within a range

Tags: python, index-error

I am trying to build a strong password checker using Python.  The conditions of the password are as follows:

- It has at least 6 characters and at most 20 characters.
- It must contain at least one lowercase letter, at least one uppercase letter,
  and at least one digit.
- It must NOT contain three repeating characters in a row ("...aaa..." is weak, but "...aa...a..." is strong, assuming other conditions are met).

Write a function strongPasswordChecker(s), that takes a string s as input, and return the MINIMUM change required to make s a strong password. If s is already strong, return 0.

Insertion, deletion or replace of any one character are all considered as one change.

The following is my attempt:

```
import re

class Solution:
    def strongPasswordChecker(self, s: str) -> int:

        # Holds the change
        change = 0

        # Checks if the password length is less than 6
        if len(s) < 6:
            change += 6 - len(s)

        # Checks if the password length is greater than 20
        elif len(s) > 20:
            change += len(s) - 20

        # Checks if the password has at least one digit
        elif re.search(r'\d', s):
            change += 1

        # Checks if the password has at least one upper case letter
        elif re.search(r'[A-Z]', s):
            change += 1

        # Checks if the password has at least one lower case letter
        elif re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
            change += 1

        # Checks for repeating characters
        for i in range(1, len(s)):
            if i >= 3 and i < len(s):
                if s[i] == s[i + 1] and s[i + 1] == s[i + 2]:
                    change += 1

        return change
```

Despite checking for the repeating characters with the if statement above, I'm still getting the following error:

`IndexError: String Index out of range`

Comment: On a separate issue: shouldn't all your regex expressions have not infront.  For instance shouldn't `elif re.search(r'\d', s):` be `elif not re.search(r'\d', s):`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this statement can go out of bounds potentially, for example when `i == len(s) - 1` then `s[i + 1]` and `s[i + 2]` will both index out of bounds.

```
for i in range(1, len(s)):
    if i >= 3 and i < len(s):
        if s[i] == s[i + 1] and s[i + 1] == s[i + 2]:
            change += 1
```

If you want to make sure you don't have groups of 3 or longer, I'd use `itertools.groupby`

```
>>> any(len(list(g)) > 2 for k, g in groupby('aabbcc'))
False
>>> any(len(list(g)) > 2 for k, g in groupby('aabbbbbcc'))
True
```

To replace your `for` loop in your code, you'd use this like

```
elif any(len(list(g)) > 2 for k, g in groupby(s)):
    change += 1
```

Comment: Doesn't your code just check only for `aabbcc` and `aabbbbbcc`?

Comment: Obviously that was just an example, you should pass the string `s` in your case

Comment: How do I use this in an if statement?

Comment: @OnurOzbek See the edit on the bottom of my answer, you can use this expression as another `elif` case